# xhost setting at boot

Tags: command-line, lightdm

I am able to set xhost at boot in Fedora by editing `/etc/gdm/Init/Default` and for example add:

```
/usr/bin/xhost +local:
```

How can similar be done in Ubuntu?  I want that the

```
/usr/bin/xhost +local:
```

command is executed when the system is sitting at login prompt.

Answer (score 15):

The `xhost` command needs an active X server to run, it can run at the login screen, for example when `lightdm` loads. 
You can enable it by editing `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and adding the line:

```
display-setup-script=/home/user/bin/xhost.sh
```

example `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
display-setup-script=/home/user/bin/xhost.sh
```

example `/home/user/bin/xhost.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
xhost +
```

It works on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS, and it was needed to enable a Java application that needed X and was run by Tomcat 6.

Comment: you might need to make the xhost.sh script executable with:
chmod +x /home/user/bin/xhost.sh

Comment: Works in Xubuntu 18.04, but make sure the script is executable as @George Litos mentioned, otherwise your system won't boot.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

Edit `~/.xinitrc`:

```
export DISPLAY=":0.0"
xhost +
openbox
```

Note: in my specific setup, I'm running only **openbox**. Normally that file is empty or missing in Ubuntu. My guess is that you could remove the "openbox" line and it would work, but I don't have a way to test it right now. If it doesn't work, replace the last line for your window manager command.

Comment: `xhost:  unable to open display ":0.0"`

Comment: @alper : Probably you are connecting remotely and there is no display or X available? Check: https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi

Answer (score 1):

`~/.xinitrc` did not work for me on Ubuntu 14.04 but the following in `~/.profile` did. On each login, GUI/terminal/SSH/etc..., the script will run so I redirect `stdout` to silence the output.

```
xhost +local: > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 17.10. It could be that my system was not properly configured. Anyway, in my case, I added

```
xhost + SI:localuser:root > /dev/null
```

at the bottom of my `~/.bashrc` file and it worked.  I don't know if this is a security risk. I share that in case someone else is in the same situation and trust that adding root to the list of privileged X server users should be OK.

It is suggested [here on ubuntuhandbook.org](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/10/ubuntu-17-10-tip-graphical-apps-doesnt-launch-via-root-sudo-gksu/)

You can test it directly on the terminal first:

```
xhost + SI:localuser:root
xhost -
```

The second line makes sure that only those in the list have access to the X server. Then try "Edit as administrator", after right clicking on a file or directly execute

```
pkexec gedit
```

If this does not work, then it is pointless to make the command permanent in `~/.bashrc`.

To be more precise, I first executed

```
xhost
```

to see which users had access to the X server. I saw that the format was `SI:localuser:dominic` where `dominic` is my login name.  So, I used the same format `SI:localuser:root`  to add the `root` user.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant of @GeorgeLitos's answer, with these changes:

- Don't directly modify `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, as this is a system-owned file that may be overwritten by system upgrades. Instead, use the extension directory `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/`. This also means that other settings don't need to be duplicated in there.
- No need for a separate shell script; the command can be directly placed into the configuration file.

Just create a file (as user root) `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/xhost.conf` with these contents:

```
[SeatDefaults]
display-setup-script=xhost +
```

This works on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

The following method actually runs `xhost +` *after* log in, but it is less invasive than others and doesn't require root credentials:

- Create a script file `~/scripts/xhost_plus.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
xhost +local:
```

- Make it executable `chmod a+x scripts/xhost_plus.sh`
- Run the "Startup Application Preferences" and add the script. First browse for the command, and then assign an appropriate name and description.

Answer (score -1):

Edit the file `/etc/rc.local` (with `sudo`) and add the command before the last command (`exit 0`).

Comment: This wont work(and I tried never the less and it doesnt work). Because that script will not have access rights to change that setting at first place. It has to be done as lightdm user?

Answer (score -1):

Add the following line to `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`

```
xhost +local:
```