# Cannot connect to X Server when running app with sudo

Tags: display, sudo, xserver

When I am running some software using `sudo` command it showing error like

```
cannot connect to X server
```

For example if I run the following command:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

I am getting following command

```
(gedit:6758): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=84b871d735f31ffe014dc9ba00000009 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' 
exited with non-zero exit status 1: 
Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed. 
Cannot open display:
Run 'gedit --help' to see a full list of available command line options.
```

Or if I am running `super-boot-manager` I am getting following error

```
buc: cannot connect to X server
```

Please help.

Comment: Where do you run `super-boot-manger` from?

Comment: First I have tried to run `super-boot-manager` directly from unity luncher, it did not worked. Then I have tried it from terminal, then I got those error massage.

Comment: As in a terminal within the graphical user environment? What does: `echo $DISPLAY` say? You should run it without `sudo` as `super-boot-manager` runs `sudo` internally.

Comment: `echo $DISPLAY` is giving `:0.0`. And I am not running `super-boot-manager` as `sudo`. I am running just using command `super-boot-manager` from terminal.

Comment: also If I am not using the part `DISPLAY=$DISPLAY` in command `gedit` is not opening using `sudo`

Comment: `buc` might be running as a different user, try removing the X restrictions with `xhost +`.

Comment: Finally the problem is solved. I have just added the line: `Defaults env_keep="DISPLAY XAUTHORITY"` at the end of `visudo`. Thanks to all, specially @Thor for kind help.

Comment: Nice solution, forgot about `sudoers` `env_keep`.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer, it would make it easier for others to find.

Comment: I've made a script for this purpose: gist.github.com/wachambo/bd22e12db2d5a46dc109bd0d553733be

Comment: Can you please hep me with this issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71464381/java-runtime-execution-not-working-in-cron-job-reboot-showing-error-unable-to

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to allow the root user access to the X server:

```
xhost local:root
```

And point the command to the right `DISPLAY`:

```
sudo DISPLAY=$DISPLAY gedit /etc/profile
```

Comment: That solved the problem with opening `gedit` as `sudo`, but still can't lunch `super-boot-manager`. It is showing same error

Comment: [I've just learned that](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#General_workarounds) `sudo -H` should be used when starting graphical applications, to avoid file corruption of X-related files.

Comment: setting the DISPLAY in sudo was not even required for me - Debian Buster.

Comment: How can I make this permanent?

Comment: @user508402: that depends on many things. You should probably post this as a new question, where you detail your current setup, i.e. shell, window manager etc.

Answer (score 20):

Finally the problem is solved. I have just added the line:

```
Defaults env_keep="DISPLAY XAUTHORITY"
```

at the end of `visudo`.

To do that you have to run:

```
sudo visudo
```

it will open the file then add the above line at the end.

Thanks to all, specially @Thor for kind help

Comment: Defaults env_keep="DISPLAY" works for me.

Comment: I have been searching high and low for this answer forever.  I wish I could upvote both of you multiple times for your answers.  Thank you so very much!  :)

Answer (score 5):

Supplementing [@Thor's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/175615/618353), run:

```
xhost local:root
```

before `sudo gedit`. To make this permanent, add the line

```
xhost local:root
```

to the `~/.xinitrc` <sup>1</sup> file. Create the file if it doesn't exist.

---

<sup>1</sup> https://askubuntu.com/a/720120/452398

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer that provides a non-permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

set `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` variable environment before running your scrip.
for example in `systemctl`  service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Clock

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/clock.py
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
KillMode=process
TimeoutSec=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```