# Ubuntu 15.04: GUI disappeared after trying to install nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, gui

My first problem was that playing videos made everything freeze - totem was using almost all my cpu power. To solve this I installed nvidia drivers with

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-###

Where ### was a number I found using http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx (for my card Geforce 630M).

This seemed to work. Video playing no longer froze my laptop (which is an Acer Aspire V3-571g if it matters). However, when I connected a second monitor I got some issues. Half of the second screen would be "cut off", only showing black. Entering nvidia-settings only showed the laptop screen

To solve this I found various questions and forum threads suggesting to do install nvidia-current instead. I did that, and ever since the GUI hasn't worked. I've tried things like

> sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

and I've tried removing that /etc/X11/xorg.conf file - nothing has worked so far.

Any suggestions on what I can do?

Edit: I'm getting "Unable to connect to X server" now, when I go into terminal with ctrl+alt+F1.

UPDATE: I didn't manage to solve the problem, and in the end I just reinstalled Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers) first and then report back by leaving a comment @Fabby

Comment: Thanks @Fabby - I hadn't seen that answer. It would've saved my a lot of time googling, but I couldn't find anything in there that I hadn't already tried. In the end I reinstalled ubuntu and I'm using the nouveau drivers without great issues. If I try to use the nvidia drivers again, I'll update here on how it goes.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the problem went away - I'm still unable to use ubuntu. Everything freezes when playing videos, and while nvidia-drivers solves that I'm then unable to use multiple monitors. Just looks like nvidia doesn't play well with ubuntu :)

Comment: IMHO, It's still better to let the closure run its course and ask a new *specific* question with your new system.  In the mean time you know more already, so your question *will* be more specific!  **;-)**

Comment: I agree! I was just curious whether it would get a "solved"-tag or something :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

"Ubuntu 15.04 seems to have an issue with nvidia drivers." This is a common problem...

First, lets get Ubuntu to a 'clean' state, without any nvidia drivers installed:

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | awk '$2~/nvidia/ {print $2}')
```

Next, let's remove the x-server error - follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175611/cannot-connect-to-x-server-when-running-app-with-sudo/175615#175615) guide.

Now, we'll try to set up the Nvidia GT 630 drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304 nvidia-304-updates
```

If it still doesn't work, then try upgrading your kernel

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

And try again...

You can install the latest NVIDIA drivers by adding the new PPA to your system.

To do so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-355
```

And as OMG! Ubuntu! say: 

**Remember: if the PPA breaks your system you are allowed to keep both halves.** ;D

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it didn't work. I first went to the folder with the .run file and ran  
> sudo bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.30.run --uninstall  
Then I did everything else, though I didn't have xserver-xorg-video-nv installed. But in the end I got the same result as before - background image showing but nothing working.

Comment: @L42 You ran what?

Comment: sudo bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.30.run --uninstall

Comment: @L42 New edit, perhaps it will work for you. Most likely it won't...

Comment: I'm getting "Conflicts: xorg-driver-binary" for both nvidia-304 and nvidia-304-updates. Not sure what to do

Comment: "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Comment: @L42 It seems that you _did_ have xorg-drivers...

Comment: @L42 Remove the xorg  settings with `sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-nv`

Comment: I don't have either of them now (previously I only had xserver-xorg-video-nouveau, as I said). I just typed in your command and I get "unable to locate package" for both of them.

Comment: Did you see my edit on "unable to connect to x server"?

Comment: @L42 Yet another edit. If it doesn't work... I'm lost :(

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I've tried what you said (kernels I tried at an earlier point), but I've still got the same problem. I'm gonna go ahead and reinstall ubuntu and stay away from the nvidia drivers.