# applications get stuck launched with sudo

Tags: sudo, prompt

If I launch Thunar from the command line it works, but if I try to launch Thunar using sudo, only the icon on the status bar shows up but no window; the same problem happens with gparted, synaptic and double commander, what is wrong?

Comment: This is probably `sudo` not importing `DISPLAY` from your environment. See also here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/175611/cannot-connect-to-x-server-when-running-app-with-sudo

Comment: The rationale for this default is that it is generally considered an avoidable security hazard to run GUI programs with root permissions. Of course _gparted_ and _synaptic_ really _need_ root permissions.

Comment: No one ever should run graphical applications with `sudo` ever. @HuHa the suggestions you provide are greatly outdated by now (e.g. gksudo is not anymore in the repos for years), and certainly will not work when running on Wayland (default again on Ubuntu 21.10) instead of Xorg

Comment: "Nobody ever" is one of those fundamentalist nonsense pragmas that drives me up the walls. How do you expect users to use _synaptic_, _gparted_, _qdirstat_? They all need root permissions to be useful. This attitude is what makes users go "screw those security dudes, they make the system completely unusable!" and use relaxed security settings for _everything_.

Comment: Alternatives to `gksu` are developed in order to increase the security. Synaptic and Gparted work with `pkexec`, that applies PolicyKit. I don't know about Double Commander, maybe it still needs `sudo -H`.

Answer (score 4):

### gvfs admin backend - for elevated permissions with GUI tools

In Ubuntu 17.10 (gvfs >= 1.29.4) and newer versions you can use the gvfs admin backend. Notice that you need the full path, for example

```
thunar admin:///path/to/directory
gedit admin:///path/to/file
```

so if you want to manage your `/etc` directory, you can use

```
thunar admin:///etc
```

In theory, the gvfs admin backend method (which uses PolicyKit) is better and safer (than `xhost` and `sudo -H`), regardless of the UI you use.

You don't run the whole application as root. Privilege escalation happens only when strictly necessary. See the following link and links from it,

- [sisco311's reply in the Ubuntu Forums thread 'Which best practice for using gedit as root?'](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2385818&p=13743162#post13743162)

  This is post #4. See also post #6 in the same thread.

### `pkexec`

Alternatives to `gksu` are developed in order to increase the security. Synaptic and Gparted work with `pkexec` (another PolicyKit application). See `man pkexec`.

You can run from a terminal window

```
pkexec synaptic
pkexec gparted
```

but the execution using PolicyKit is built into the graphical launch mechanism, so that you see only the pop up window asking for password.

---

But command line tools (in terminal windows) and `sudo` are often recommended when elevated permissions are necessary. A file browser open with elevated permissions makes it easy to damage the operating system by mistake.

Comment: pkexec synaptic does not work, the same for pkexec gparted

Comment: @arpho, `pkexec` works for me with `synaptic` and `gparted`. It works for me in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS both in X and Wayland sessions. Which flavour (maybe Xubuntu because you ask about Thunar) and which version are you running ( other than 20.04.3 LTS)? Or some other flavour or version? Or maybe a non-Ubuntu distro? - If you let us know details about your operating system, it will be easier to help you. Otherwise there will only be general advice.

Comment: for synaptic `synaptic-pkexec`

Comment: @arpho, use what works for *you*, maybe it is necessary to switch session from Wayland to X and/or use `xhost` and `sudo -H`. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961978#961978) (written 2017 and slightly modified after that) shows details of some methods.