# How to allow multiple users to use the X display?

Tags: unity, server, ssh

I got a physical machine running Ubuntu 12.10 server edition along with a X server + Unity.

I would like to remotely connect to this machine through SSH to run a graphical application over the remote display (which is :0). For this I wrote the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0; export DISPLAY
/path/to/my/graphical/app
```

It only works if I execute that script from the user who started X/Unity at the remote machine's boot time.

**But** I need to be able to do the same from any possible user logging in through SSH.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: `sudo xhost +` for any or `sudo xhost +username` for defined user. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/115675/xhost-setting-at-boot

Comment: Thank you for the direction! I'm going to try this as soon as I get back to work.